# What is the use of BaseColumns's _ID primary key in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

It is a bit confusing.... If I implement BaseColumns for each of my tables it automatically create an autoincremented primary key for me called _ID but then Do I need to create my own primary keys for each of my tables as well or is it redundant or even not necessary?

In case I need my own primary key, let's say, _MyID, I guess the primary key will be formed by _ID and my own (_MyID), right? so in this case, it would be possible to insert the more than one register with the same _MyID.... as _ID is autoincremented automatically, that is:

```
_ID      _MyID  Other Fields.....
1         1000  ....
2         1000  ....
3         1000  ....
```

... and so on

so in this case, how to control that only one register can have the value 1000 for _MyID?

Also, I guess I can use _ID column to act as a foreign key with other tables, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main use for `BaseColumns._ID` is that Android's [`CursorAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.html) will look for that column name in the cursor you give it. There may be other classes that do the same, but I can't think of any off the top of my head. If you aren't using `CursorAdapter`, then there's really nothing binding you to using _id as a column name in your table and you can name the column however you like.

> it automatically create an autoincremented primary key for me called _ID

There is nothing automatic about it based on what you've shown so far. You will only have such a column if you executed SQL like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tableName (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ...);
```

You can just as easily leave it out or give a different name to the primary key. Furthermore, there is nothing that requires your primary key to be auto-incremented; as long as the values are unique, it satisfies the primary key requirement. In other words, this is fine too:

```
CREATE TABLE tableName (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ...);
```

> In case I need my own primary key, let's say, _MyID, I guess the primary key will be formed by _ID and my own (_MyID), right?

Not quite. You would have to do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tableName (_id INTEGER, _myId INTEGER, ..., PRIMARY KEY(_id, myId));
```

This creates a composite key, but note that neither of the two columns are themselves declared as primary key. Honestly though, if you don't need such an arrangement, then stick to one primary key.

One last thing:

If you *are* planning to use `CursorAdapter`, you might want to name the column _id for convenience, but even then you don't have to. All that matters is the *cursor* has a column by that name. The actual column in the table can have a different name, you just have to alias it at query time so that it has the proper name in the cursor:

```
SELECT _myId as _id, ... FROM ...;
```

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed information, point for you. One thing, I guess that it is a must for CursorAdapter that _ID column to be not only INTEGER but also PRIMARY KEY because this column must be unique, that is, cannot exist more than one record with the same _ID value, right? but if I use a composite primary key, let's say, PRIMARY KEY (_ID, myId) then in this case is possible that more than one register have the same _ID value but not the same primary key.... so in this case, what happens? I guess cursor will not work as it expects _ID value to be unique....

Comment: Finally, If I declare _ID as primary key but I do not declare as AUTOINCREMENTED, when I insert a record, _ID is automatically genereated but with which value? Using Autoincremented is clear, it will be 1, 2, 3 and so on....

Comment: In SQLite, every table has an internally-managed column called ROWID. _This_ is the column for which integer values are auto generated. If (and only if) you declare a column INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, then that column becomes an _alias_ for ROWID. The AUTOINCREMENT keyword only changes slightly the algorithm that generates a ROWID. So you don't even need to declare an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column, you can just `SELECT rowid AS _id`. You can insert values manually into an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column, either the one you declare or ROWID if you don't declare one, but the values must be all unique.